# How to set-up an app for multiple users to make withdrawals which connects to Exodus wallet

Tags: usdt, withdrawal

I want to connect or create a system where users in my team can make withdrawals from an Exodus wallet without having access to the actual wallet.

The withdrawals would be approved by the wallet owner.

Any suggestions or pre-built apps out there already?